# Task takes 15 minutes with one processor and 20 minutes with two processors

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, parallelism, multithreading

This is the command, run at the root of an NTFS partition from a Debian 12 VM (VirtualBox)

`$ (find . -type f -exec cat {} \;) | pv | wc -c`

I was trying to check that all files are readable. It's a broken Windows 10 filesystem that seems to give disk errors from Windows so I thought of doing this test to see how Linux deals with that filesystem.

It finished after 15 minutes. Then I realized that the VM had only one processor, turned it off, set it to 2 processors in VirtualBox, and out of curiosity run the command again and it took 20 minutes. I repeated both tests and again they took 15 and 20 minutes.

Using `top` I see that the processes with more load are `mount.ntfs`, `find`, and `wc`

What could be the cause for this?

**EDIT:**

The storage is fully SSD-based

Comment: Throughput depends on many factors, not just CPU.  Did you have sufficient memory available?  Was the VM having to page and/or discard clean buffers?  What about you r I/O bandwidth, or for that matter the disk performance.  Head contention?  On top of that, remember that the VM is "virtual", what was the real bare metal underneath doing?  You'd need to supply a lot more information to get a realistic answer.  One tip: keep an eye on the processor states, IO limitations show up as "wa" wait states, system housekeeping as "sy".  And check the host at the same time.

Comment: Memory is 700 MB used of 4 GB total in the VM. The host's memory is more full, but not to the point of swapping or thrashing. What is head contention?

Comment: Head contention is basically about too many processes trying to read from the disk at the same time. This would be possible with another CPU running, other processes also accessing the disk while your `find` command runs.  More CPUs == more possibility for processes running concurrently == more disk activity == slower disk throughput for each individual process.